# JPanel placing other panel instances

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

So I'm creating a shop system, and I'm placing instances of JPanel inside another JPanel. I want the JPanel instances to allign so there's three instances per line, not sure how to explain it. Anyway here's a picture.

[image]

I've tried separating the x and y axis of the instances with this:

```
int posX = 5;
int posY = 5;
if(shopItemDisplayIteratorX == 0) {
    posX = 5;
    shopItemDisplayIteratorX++;
} else if(shopItemDisplayIteratorX == 1) {
    posX = 180;
    shopItemDisplayIteratorX++;
} else if(shopItemDisplayIteratorX == 2) {
    posX = 355;
    shopItemDisplayIteratorX = 0;
}
if(shopItemDisplayIteratorY == 0) {
    posY = 5;
    shopItemDisplayIteratorY++;
} else if(shopItemDisplayIteratorY == 1) {
    posY = 263;
    shopItemDisplayIteratorY++;
} else if(shopItemDisplayIteratorY == 2) {
    posY = 521;
    shopItemDisplayIteratorY = 0;
}
```

Not the best of code I know, but it's just for testing. This isn't working, as you can see by the picture, it places 2 instances of the panel only. It's like it's skipping the other 3 instances.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Layout like `GridLayout`. For example,

```
yourParentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
//add your 3 components
```

This should align your components horizontally.

Everything about Layouts can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: I tried that but it's not sizing them appropriately. http://i.gyazo.com/c510e82016681a6dfe2197fe5c2d20ac.png

Comment: So the panels are too small? Do your parent components have a preferred size? If so, that will limit the sizes of the inner panels.